# How to identify tapped element ID in Android?

Tags: android, selenium, automation, adb, appium

I am doing a research project which is included Android automation. It is required to automate steps which record while user tap on screen.

I spend entirely 2 days to find a proper way to identify tapped element on screen though PC side (on device itself is also OK).

we need to provide ID, text etc to automation frameworks. this is something like reverse version of a automation framework. Need to record steps like selenium addon.

Can someone suggest me a way to achieve my requirement. No need sample code. looking for a idea on how to implement this requirement.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is the approach that will help you.

1) Get all elements in the document

2) Add a custom event listener  for each and every step

3) Track the tap with in event listener

Here is the sample code how I did it in one of my chrome addons.

```
this.AddEventListeners = function()
{
    var document = window.document;
    var elements = this.GetAllElements(document.body);

    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)   {
        // not sure if it's onTouchEvent event or something else (update the event accordingly in the below line)
        elements[i].addEventListener("onTouchEvent", customTapEvent, false);
    }   
    this.haveEventListeners = true;
}
```

**GetAllElements method:**

```
this.GetAllElements = function(element)
{
    var elements = new Array();

    if (element && element.hasChildNodes()) {
        elements.push(element);

        var childs = element.childNodes;

        for (var i = 0; i < childs.length; i++) {
            if (childs[i].hasChildNodes()) {
                elements = elements.concat(this.GetAllElements(childs[i]));
            }
            else if (childs[i].nodeType == 1) {
                elements.push(childs[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    return elements;
}
```

Write the logic in the`customTapEvent` method.

Comment: @www Was this helpful? Let me know if you need any more info.

Answer (score 0):

In order to record your events you need to use **Appium** (android + iOS). For steps you can try the **cucumber** library. You find all you need on youtube.